# React Typescript: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The console is showing a new Object but I still get the error

```
const GetNo = (): string => {
        console.log(record);
        if (record.no !== "")
            return record.no;   //<-- Cannot read properties of undefined
        else
            return todos[todos.length - 1].no + 1;
    }
```

console:

[image]

EDIT:
record is type of object (see picture above) and im creating it via `Button onClick` where i modify a state `this.setState({ selectedRecord: new ToDoClass()` . After that I redner the `FC` with the form.

EDIT 2:
I tried the new Syntax:

```
const GetNo = (): string => {
        if (record == null) {
            console.log("1");
            return "2";
        }
        else if (record.no != null) {
            console.log("2");
            return record.no;
        }
        else {
            console.log("3");
            return todos[todos.length - 1].no + 1;
        }
    }
```

and when the record is: `new ToDoClass()` it return in the console a *2* but it should go inside the first statement?!

Comment: What's the type of `record` and where is it initialized?

Comment: @tokland I edit the post

Comment: where is record defined in your code, e.g. `const record = ....`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it behaves like this but I solved it with a Try-Catch statement.

```
const GetNo = (): string => {
   try {
      if (record.no !== "")
         return record.no;
      else
         return todos[todos.length - 1].no + 1;
   }
   catch {
      return "0";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your object `record` is defined outside of the function and may not be initialized at the execution time of the function.

I recommend you to:

- Pass the object as a parameter of the function
- Check that record is defined

By the way if you're using Typescript and there is a possibility that the record is not defined when passed to the function, you should get a warning at the line where you call `GetNo(record)`.

```
const GetNo = (record: Record): string => {
   if (record) {
     // ...
   }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful!

Comment: The check that the record is defined works but now it always return this if statement and dont go into the other statements